# python-telegram-bot in django application

Tags: django, python-telegram-bot

I’m trying to start `python-telegram-bot` in a web application with the django framework. To do this, I follow any example from the Telegram library and end up calling the method `application.run_polling()`. I know it’s not the best option because this blocks my web server, and I want to replace it with a better one, but I can’t find it.

According to official documentation, there is a tip that indicates the following:

> When combining python-telegram-bot with other asyncio based frameworks, using this method is likely not the best choice, as it blocks the event loop until it receives a stop signal as described above. Instead, you can manually call the methods listed below to start and shut down the application and the updater. Keeping the event loop running and listening for a stop signal is then up to you.

And then I find the following section:

> See also
>
> initialize(), start(), stop(), shutdown() telegram.ext.Updater.start_polling(), telegram.ext.Updater.stop(), run_webhook()

I’ve tried to understand the methods in the list, but I can’t figure out how to run `python-telegram-bot` in the background and not affect my main server.

Are there any links or documents that expand the information or detail the steps to follow in these cases?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Telegram I run it from an app configured in django as follows:

```py
import asyncio

from django.apps import AppConfig
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ContextTypes, Application, CommandHandler

from TaixTracking.configApp import ConfigApp


async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text("Help!")


async def start_telegram():
    application = Application.builder().token(ConfigApp().get_value('telegram', 'token', '')).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    await application.initialize()
    await application.start()
    await application.updater.start_polling()
    print('Telegram load')


class CommunicationConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'communication'

    def ready(self):
        if not ConfigApp().is_telegram_launch():
            ConfigApp().set_telegram_launch(True)
            asyncio.run(start_telegram())
```

Comment: Have you seen [this wiki entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#running-ptb-alongside-other-asyncio-frameworks)? If that does not solve your problem, please try to narrow down where the problems are for you :)

Comment: I had not seen that entry on the wiki, I have made the changes indicated but I can not get it to work (the bot does not respond to the help command)

Comment: `application.initialize, `application.start` and `application.updater.start_polling` are all coroutine functions, i.e. you need to `await` them.

Comment: First thank you @CallMeStag for the help. I just made the changes you indicated, I forced the function to be `async` and I pulled it out of `ready`, but it still doesn’t work. When telling the bot `/help` I do not answer

Comment: It wont answer, because you havent set up a handler in the code snippet you provided.

Comment: I do not understand, I thought that with the line `application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))` already associated the command to my function, and when using it in the bot execute said function.